# Vue Replace Navbar With Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

Vue newbie here. With the out-of-box default app created by Vue-CLI, including Vue Router, you have the top navbar with the Home and About links. What I want is: when you click on the About link, instead of updating the content below the navbar, it will update the entire page i.e. making the navbar disappear.

[image]

In App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="nav">
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
    <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
  </div>
  <router-view />
</template>
```

The router is set-up in `router/index.js` as:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    name: "About",
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/About.vue"),
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

This is to simulate a typical login page where you often don't get navbar.

I played with nested routers but no luck. I'm using Vue 3.

Comment: But nested routes are indeed the right solution...

Comment: I mean one of the possible solutions. Other would be to display navbar section conditionally only if user is logged in....

Comment: Thanks @MichalLevý, I'll need to try nested routes again tomorrow. Regarding hiding the navbar after user is logged in: I want to hide the navbar at the log-in or sign-up page.

Comment: That's fine - in both cases user is not logged in...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by extracting the nav links into its own component, and only display the nav links on the pages that need it. This means in the sign-up page I do not include the nav links.

So after creating the default Vue-CLI starting app, I removed the nav components:

```
<template>
  <!-- <div id="nav">
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
    <router-link to="/about">About</router-link> |
    <router-link to="/signin">Sign In</router-link>
  </div> -->
  <router-view />
</template>
```

And created a new Nav.vue component:

```
<template>
  <div id="nav">
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
    <router-link to="/about">About</router-link> |
    <router-link to="/signin">Sign In</router-link>
  </div>
</template>
```

Added the Nav component to the pages where I want the nav to show, e.g. Home.vue:

```
<template>
  <Nav />
  <div class="home">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="../assets/logo.png" />
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App" />
  </div>
</template>
```

I do not include the nav in my sign-in:

```
<template>This is the SIGN IN page - note there is no navigation links.</template>
```

Being a Vue noob, not sure if the above is the best approach, but it is working for now.